# setup:upgrade results in error: /var cannot be accesed (but has 777) Magento2

Tags: magento2, permissions, setup

Im trying to installing a new plugin, but it keeps saying that the magento-php-script has no access to /var, but /var has chmod 0777. All childrenfolders have 777, except for composer_home which has 777 as well.

> [Exception]
>   Missing write permissions to the following directories:
>   '/home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/var'

However, I need to upgrade the instance in order to activate the module I want to install. If I keep the module in the filesystem, I get an exception error with following content:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:208:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magenest_ProductLabel data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0";i:1;s:2748:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#3 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#7 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#11 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /home/ccsammelfiguren/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Seems like the module isnt acknoledged by magento since setup:upgrade wasnt successful. I already tried to manipulate the FilePermissions.php and tried to find broken symlinks (there are none).

Any idea, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

switch magento user to root and run this command will fixed this error.

```
[root@localhost m2.com]# magento setup:upgrade && chmod -R 777 ./
```

And this will no error again. If I switch magento user it will always show the file permission in `/var/*` even though the files permission was set to be 777